# How to bind localhost to 127.0.0.1 on Mac?

Tags: macos, localhost

I have a running web application on my local machine. To get access to it I can use `localhost:8080`. But when I try to use `http://127.0.0.1:8080` address my browser says: `The 127.0.0.1 page isn’t working`.

Ping to it does not work as well:

```
ping 127.0.0.1:8080
ping: cannot resolve 127.0.0.1:8080: Unknown host
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Please add more info. What app is this? Is it the built in Apache server or something else?

Comment: How are you binding to the address in your app. My guess is that it is binding to ::1 (IPv6 localhost). You should be able to change the listen address to be 127.0.0.1 as opposed to the name. Or if you want to listen on all address bind to 0.0.0.0

Comment: As a side issue, ping doesn't allow specification of a port as the ping service runs on a predefined port. Try just `ping 127.0.0.1` and it should work. If you want to test a connection to a specific port, try using `telnet` instead, e.g. `telnet 127.0.0.1 8080`

Comment: "Ping service" is not running on a predefined port. "Ping service" - or ICMP - just doesn't use the concept of ports. It's got nothing to do with UDP or TCP.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Open a terminal window and type this line:

```
sudo open -a TextEdit /etc/hosts
```

You will be prompt to type in your admin password and your host file will open in TextEdit. Add this line in your host file :

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

Save the file and close. That's it.

Comment: Tried this and a whole bunch of similar commands to open /etc/hosts but every time soon as I start typing I get a popup saying you don't own the file and don't have permission to write to it. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Jeremiah that's what the `sudo` part is supposed to take care of. Should work fine unless you're on leased hardware, in which case you'll need to bring it to IT and have them do this for you.

Comment: For some reason, TextEdit doesn't seem to recognize the `sudo` privileges. Using Sublime Text, it worked for me (`sudo open -a Sublime\ Text /etc/hosts`).

Comment: `sudo vi /etc/hosts` will also work